# Obtener el ultimo ID?

Tags: php

Tengo este código.

¿Cómo puedo obtener el ultimo ID que se me refleje en el momento de hacer el formulario?

Formulario:

```
<?php
        include ("dbmpc.php");
        $tmc= new Database();
        if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)){
          $rmmpc = $tmc->sanitize($_POST['rmmpc']);
          $nmpv = $tmc->sanitize($_POST['nmpv']);
          $tproducto = $tmc->sanitize($_POST['tproducto']);
          $tvehiculo = $tmc->sanitize($_POST['tvehiculo']);
          $placa = $tmc->sanitize($_POST['placa']);
          $remolque = $tmc->sanitize($_POST['remolque']);
          $nconductor = $tmc->sanitize($_POST['nconductor']);
          $cc = $tmc->sanitize($_POST['cc']);
          $cdtrtelefono = $tmc->sanitize($_POST['cdtrtelefono']);
          $ttransporte = $tmc->sanitize($_POST['ttransporte']);
          $fentrada = $tmc->sanitize($_POST['fentrada']);
          $coplanta = $tmc->sanitize($_POST['coplanta']);
          $cdplanta = $tmc->sanitize($_POST['cdplanta']);
          $nub = $tmc->sanitize($_POST['nub']);
          $fsalida = $tmc->sanitize($_POST['fsalida']);
          $fecha = $tmc->sanitize($_POST['fecha']);

          $res = $tmc->create($rmmpc, $nmpv, $tproducto, $tvehiculo, $placa, $remolque, $nconductor, $cc, $cdtrtelefono, $ttransporte, $fentrada, $coplanta, $cdplanta, $nub, $fsalida, $fecha);
          if($res){
            $message= "Datos ingresado con éxito";
            $class="alert alert-success";
          }else{
            $message="No se pudieron ingresar los datos";
            $class="alert alert-danger";
          }

          ?>
```

Código PHP:

```
public function create($rmmpc,$nmpv,$tproducto,$tvehiculo,$placa,$remolque,$nconductor,$cc,$cdtrtelefono,$ttransporte,$fentrada,$coplanta,$cdplanta,$nub,$fsalida,$fecha){
            $sql = "INSERT INTO `tmc` (rmmpc, nmpv, tproducto, tvehiculo, placa, remolque, nconductor, cc, cdtrtelefono, ttransporte, fentrada, coplanta, cdplanta, nub, fsalida, fecha) VALUES ('$rmmpc', '$nmpv', '$tproducto', '$tvehiculo','$placa', '$remolque', '$nconductor', '$cc', '$cdtrtelefono', '$ttransporte', '$fentrada', '$coplanta', '$cdplanta', '$nub', '$fsalida','$fecha')";
            $res = mysqli_query($this->con, $sql);
            if($res){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: La manera de sacar la última id insertada en tu caso es : $last_id = mysqli_insert_id($this->con);

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Te hago una pregunta filosófica, **¿qué es el último id?**, ¿el último que se insertó basándose en una columna auto_increment?, ¿el último basándose en la fecha?, ¿el último basándose en una columna del tipo `int`?  ... ¿el último basándose en la inserción que acaba de ocurrir? ... ¿?

Comment: Saludos en este caso ( el último que se insertó basándose en una columna auto_increment ) pero ya que planteaste ( el último basándose en la inserción que acaba de ocurrir ) pudiera esta posibilidad también y muchas gracias por atender mi dudas y tu ayuda en este tema te lo agradezco mucho

Comment: En ese caso, la solución es la que ha comentado @IñigoIrigoyenErquicia, usar la propiedad [`insert_id`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.insert-id.php) de mysqli, haciendo algo así: **`if($res){
                return mysqli_insert_id($this->conn);
            }else{
                return false;
            }`** ahí te devolvería el último `id` insertado, a condición de que en la tabla  haya una columna auto_incremental.

Comment: Muchas gracias y disculpa otra pregunta es que no consigo verlo en mi formulario porque ingrese tu aporte en BD y perfecto funciona, soy nuevo en esto por favor si eres tan amable te lo agradezco mucho este es formulario completo

Comment: No entiendo lo que refieres sobre el formulario ¿?

Comment: Eso lo hice pero no captas la idea y te explico pediátricamente: tengo 1 index que me arroja todos los datos  entre eso los ID y todos perfecto luego tengo un botón para nuevo registro, lo cual quiero en el formulario 2 posibles formas 1) Después que cree el registro me muestre cual fue el ID asignado en ese momento  2) me muestre el siguiente ID que debe asignar antes de crear el registro, es lo que busco y mi archivos son: index.php y bd.php y formulario.php

Comment: Ya te lo expliqué. La función `create` te devolverá el último `ID`, luego puedes usar ese dato y mostrarlo donde quieras, no entiendo entonces cuál es el problema.

Comment: los datos que suministraste esta perfecto y funciona perfecto, y lo agregue en mi bd.php pero en formulario.php no se que poner para que se devuelva la consulta del ID al momento de crear el registro

Comment: tiene razón en todos y esta super perfecto la cos es que no se que comando o como declara los formulario o donde sea me aparezca esos daos, hay estoy truncado

Comment: Victor ese es ya otro tema que se sale del propósito de esta pregunta. Stackoverflow funciona por preguntas, no podemos mezclar o añadir cosas y cosas en la misma pregunta. ¿Ya sabes como devolver el último ID, cierto? Ahora se trata de cómo tener un formulario, enviarle datos a la base de datos, recuperar la respuesta del servidor y mostrarla en alguna parte. Lo mejor para esto sería usar Ajax, pero eso es ya otro tema. Sea como sea, aquí hay varias preguntas ya sobre casos parecidos, puedes revisarlas y si aún así no das con el asunto puedes plantear la tuya propia explicando el contexto.

Comment: la verdad no m supe formular a pregunta disculpas de todas maneras tu función fue eficiente

Answer (score 0):

Si tu id es un autoincrement, entonces al momento de insertar, si todo salió bien, haz otra consulta en la que haces una select de la tabla que hiciste el registro, con un ORDER BY id DESC, limit 1.

Si puedes encapsularlo en un procedimiento mejor

Comment: Eso lo hice pero no captas la idea y te explico pediátricamente: tengo 1 index que me arroja todos los datos  entre eso los ID y todos perfecto luego tengo un botón para nuevo registro, lo cual quiero en el formulario 2 posibles formas 1) Después que cree el registro me muestre cual fue el ID asignado en ese momento  2) me muestre el siguiente ID que debe asignar antes de crear el registro, es lo que busco y mi archivos son: index.php y bd.php y formulario.php

Comment: Se agradece la ayuda @Aaron pero una pregunta bien redactada debe tener siempre código y explicación. [answer] échale un ojo y actualiza la pregunta en consecuencia. Un saludo.